# javascript make functions globally available via window

Tags: javascript

I have a THREEJS script that looks similar to this,

```
import * as THREE from '../../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';

import { OrbitControls } from '../../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from '../../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

let camera, scene, renderer, model, map;

function init() {

    // Containing element, will need to be changed. _______
    const container = document.querySelector( '.visualiser__wrapper' ); 
    // ____________________________________________________

    // Init camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, container.getBoundingClientRect().width / container.getBoundingClientRect().height, 0.25, 20 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0.1, 3.5 );


    // Init scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    window.scene = scene; // For testing

    // Init renderer and add it to the container.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( container.getBoundingClientRect().width, container.getBoundingClientRect().width );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // _____________________________________________________Lighting

    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight();

    scene.add(ambientLight);
    scene.add(directionalLight);
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf3f3f3);

    // ___________________________________________________ Controls

    const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // use if there is no animation loop
    controls.minDistance = 0.2;
    controls.maxDistance = 2;
    controls.target.set( 0, 0.1, 0 );
    controls.update();


    // ___________________________________________________ Update when resized
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
}

function onWindowResize() {
    const container = document.querySelector( '.visualiser__wrapper' );

    camera.aspect = container.getBoundingClientRect().width / container.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( container.getBoundingClientRect().width, container.getBoundingClientRect().height );

    render();

}

function render() {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

// _________________________________________________________ Model Loading

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( '/wp-content/themes/storefront-child-phreak/src/images/' );

function setModel(url, callback) {
    gltfLoader.load( url, function ( gltf ) {

        if (model) scene.remove(model); // Remove the old model
        model = gltf.scene; // remember this one so we can remove it later.

        scene.add( model ); // Add new model
        render(); // Something has changed, render again.
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }

    } );
}

// ____________________________________________________________ Change roughness map

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

// Set map from texture object
function setNormalMap (texture) {
    scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if (child.material != undefined) {
            child.material.normalMap = texture;
            child.material.needsUpdate = true; // This is important, won't update without this flag
        }
    });
    // Scene has changed, needs rendering
    render();
}

// Set texture map from url, optional callbacks, complete, progress and error
function setNormalMapFromUrl(url, complete, error) {

    // load the texture
    textureLoader.load(

        url,

        function ( texture ) {

            // Find all models with materials on them
            // Apply the map
            setNormalMap(texture);
            // Callback if set
            if (complete) complete(texture);
        },
        undefined,
        function ( err ) {
            if (error) error(err);
        }
    );

};

// ____________________________________________________________ Change roughness map


// Set map from texture object
function setRoughnessMap (texture) {
    scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if (child.material != undefined) {
            child.material.roughnessMap = texture;
            child.material.needsUpdate = true; // This is important, won't update without this flag
        }
    });
    // Scene has changed, needs rendering
    render();
}

// Set texture map from url, optional callbacks, complete, progress and error
function setRoughnessMapFromUrl(url, complete, error) {

    // load the texture
    textureLoader.load(

        url,

        function ( texture ) {

            // Find all models with materials on them
            // Apply the map
            setRoughnessMap(texture);
            // Callback if set
            if (complete) complete(texture);
        },
        undefined,
        function ( err ) {
            if (error) error(err);
        }
    );

};


// ____________________________________________________________ Change texture map


// Set map from texture object
function setMap (texture) {
    scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if (child.material != undefined) {
            child.material.map = texture;
            child.material.needsUpdate = true; // This is important, won't update without this flag
        }
    });
    // Scene has changed, needs rendering
    render();
}

// Set texture map from url, optional callbacks, complete, progress and error
function setMapFromUrl(url, complete, error) {

    // load the texture
    textureLoader.load(

        url,

        function ( texture ) {

            // Find all models with materials on them
            // Apply the map
            setMap(texture);
            // Callback if set
            if (complete) complete(texture);
        },
        undefined,
        function ( err ) {
            if (error) error(err);
        }
    );

};

window.setMap = setMap; // For testing;

// ____________ Begin 

init();
// For simplicity I am loading textures after the model is loaded
// This can be all loaded at the same time then applied together
setModel('model', function() {
    setMapFromUrl('map');
    setNormalMapFromUrl('normalmap');
    setRoughnessMapFromUrl('roughnessmap');
});

render();
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

This code is loading in like this,

`<script type="module" src="path/to/script"></script>`

I want make the `setModel` `setNormalMapFromUrl`, `setRoughnessMapFromUrl`, `setMapFromUrl` functions to be available outside of this, i.e I want to be able to call one of this functions from another place in the source code.

Can I add these functions to the window global, and if so how?

Comment: Change `function setModel(url, callback) {` to `window.setModel = (url, callback) => {` ?

Comment: This question is not specific to `three.js`, but is a general JavaScript scoping question.  I recommend restructuring your question with a simplified example of what you want to do, and remove the `three.js` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make any object available in window's scope, just simply add them as properties to a `window` object.

#### Window Object

Window Object, is an object created once per each open window (tab) of a web browser. It mostly holds information about viewport.

Please note, that for `<iframe>` tags there are separate `window` objects created. You cannot directly communicate between iframes nor access iframes' content from window's scope. There is however a method to communicate between iframes created in a single browser window, using `Window.postMessage()` method.

To learn more about available properties and methods for Window Objects, please refer to
the following docs https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp